# Add a double space as a delimiter

Tags: matlab, text, delimiter, csv, export-to-text

I have a huge amount of large text files that need to be reformatted so that they can be read by FEAT (an MRI analysis program).  FSL reads  text files with a double space as a delimiter.  I've been using matlab to add a row of information that I need to the txt files and i'm trying to get it to export the resulting array as a text file with a double space delimiter but I can't figure out how to do it.  dlmwrite only allows for single characters to be used as delimiters.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not entirely clear from this question what is going on...

What is the exact datatype in MATLAB that you're trying to write to double space delimited text file? Do you just need to output a matrix of real doubles?

Comment: So I'm taking a text file of numbers, using dlmread to make them into a numerical array, then modifying the array and using dlmwrite on the modified array to output it as a .txt file again.  I was getting stuck because I couldn't figure out how to get dlmwrite to output a double space, but I just realized i can just use comma as a delimiter and then ctrl-f replace all the commas with a double space in the txt file itself.

Comment: Far simpler than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your own version of dlmwrite. For example:

```
function my_dlmwrite(filename, m, delimiter_string, sigfigs)
if(~ischar(delimiter_string))
    error('delimiter string should be a string');
end
if(~isnumeric(m) || ~(isreal(m)))
    error('matrix should be a real matrix of doubles')
end
if(~isscalar(sigfigs))
    error('the number of significant figures to print should be a scalar');
end
if(sigfigs < 5)
    warning('do you really want fewer than 5 significant significant digits?');
end        

fid = fopen(filename ,'W');  %open for writing and dont flush for better performance

[n_rows, n_cols] = size(m);

for(i=1:n_rows)
    fprintf(fid, '%.*g', sigfigs, m(i, 1));        
    for(j=2:n_cols)
        fprintf(fid, '%s%.*g', delimiter_string, sigfigs, m(i, j));
    end
    fprintf(fid,'\n');
end

fclose(fid);
```